# Google Sheets default value for cell for new rows after Google Form submission

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I can't seem to figure out how to auto-populate cell values for new rows in a Google sheet after Google form submission. I am building an issue tracker with Google Sheets and Forms, where users submit tickets, with the following fields: Bug, Description, Priority, Link.

On the sheets end, I want another column "status" to autopopulate with "Open"

Tried this formula when comparing to an empty col "solutions" that would always be empty upon form submission

```
=if(isblank(I2:I), "Open", "Closed")
```

But it doesn't auto-populate new form submissions. I have searched but can't seem to find anything. Anything to point me in the right direction would be great!

I'm learning theres something called google-apps-scripts.. Should i be looking into that?

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there. use this in row 1:

```
={"header"; INDEX(IF(ISBLANK(I2:I), "Open", "Closed"))}
```

Comment: That worked! I can't upvote yet as I'm a new user. Thank you! This works great, but populates entire column rows with "Open." Would it require a script of some sort if I wanted it upon new entry from Google Forms?